# Wireless-LAN TL-WN821N is not starting automatically on startup

Tags: wireless

I installed a USB-WLAN-Stick by using Windows Wireless Drivers-Application and windows drivers. It took me some time to get it run but now it works. The only problem I have got is, that it does not start automatically on ubuntu startup or the moment I log on with my account.

So I always have to manually add the following commands in the terminal:

sudo modprobe -rfv ath9k_htc
sudo modprobe -v ath9k_htc

After having done so, WLAN works perfectly. Is there a possibility to make WLAN start automatically on ubuntu startup?

Thank you for your ideas!

Comment: Could you post on a pastebin the output of `dmsg|grep ath9k_htc` ? So you need to reload the module every time. May be it did not load some firmware correctly or initialize correctly ?

Comment: The Windows Wireless Drivers tool implies that you installed a driver with ndiswrapper. This should not be needed if there is a native driver such as ath9k_htc. If both are installed, they probably conflict. Please clarify.

Comment: Thank you solsTiCe and chili5555 for your quick answer. First off all there is the pastebin link:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/11059680/

Comment: For explanation  I run a Ubuntu 15.04 server and I used to run Ubuntu 14.04. In both cases I had problems with a stable WLAN-Connection. I know that there is a native driver included for my WLAN-USB-Stick, but it does not work properly. So I had to install the Windows drivers with the NDIS-Wrapper tool. I wish that you can help me to start WLAN on Ubuntu Startup automatically, because the WLAN-Connection is very stable and works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Your pastebin implies, because of the timestamp, that the driver doesn't load on boot. It may be blacklisted as a part of the process to install ndiswrapper. Check:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Is the line *blacklist ath9k_htc* listed? If so, remove it. Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, please try, in a terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo ath9k_htc  >>  /etc/modules
exit
```

Reboot. Any improvement?

You may be able to improve stability by checking the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

If these changes are ineffective, you might try a driver parameter:

```
sudo -i
echo "options ath9k_htc nohwcrypt=1"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k_htc.conf
modprobe -r ath9k_htc
modprobe ath9k_htc
exit
```

Comment: No; it already loads automatically. OP needs to unload and then reload the module

Comment: @solsTiCe I disagree. Please see the timestamp in pastebin.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me.  First of all I want to say that this was a great help for me! @chili555 your solution works perfectly! I followed the steps you gave me above and without any error it figured out that it is the perfect solution. Once again it works. I am very happy :) Unfortunately B E F O R E  I followed chili555s commands I found out, that the WLAN - Connection is breaking again, once in a time, which makes me feel unhappy again :( One problem solved another problem has returned. What can I do so far? Greentings

Comment: In addition I want to say that WLAN Connection stability was much worse before at the moment it is working properly and I can live with that, unless it does not get worse.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Thank you! chili555 are you familiar with Lexmark multifunctional devices?

Comment: I am not. Please start a new question. If my answer has been helpful, please accept it.